# MATLAB Concatenate vectors with unequal dimensions

Tags: matlab

Lets say I have got vector1:

```
2
3
5
6
7
9
```

And a vector2:

```
1
2
3
```

Now I would like to obtain the following matrix:

```
2   1
3   2
5   3 
6   1
7   2
9   3
```

That is, I want to add vector2 as a column next to vector1 until the new column is completely filled. I have to do this with a lot of vectors with different sizes. The only thing I know in advance is that the length of vector1 is an integer multiple of the length of vector2.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I could swear that there's a duplicate for this, but I just can't find it. And the solution uses `bsxfun` to replicate the second vector, which is faster than `repmat`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) to replicate the smaller matrix.

```ml
a = [2 3 5 6 7 9]';
b = [1 2 3]';
c = [a repmat(b, length(a) / length(b), 1)]
```

Result:

```
c =

     2     1
     3     2
     5     3
     6     1
     7     2
     9     3
```

Comment: Minor remark: this will work only if `length(a) / length(b)` is a whole number.

Comment: @OlegKomarov Not just a whole number, but `b` replicated `length(a) / length(b)` must have a size that can be `horzcat`ted with `a`

Answer (score 0):

You can then replicate the vector:

```
[vector1, repmat(vector2,n,1)]
```

where `n` is your multiple of `vector2`.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an alternative

```
[x [y'; y']]
```